# Helloworld sample lambda or api gateway program not running in docker Windows 10

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS and docker. I am trying basic helloworld program in .Netcore 2.1 with SAM CLI and docker on Windows 10 Enterprise laptop and it is not working. I used out of the box project and didn't change anything in the files.

I tried following things:

```
1. Mock lambda test tool works fine. 
2. dotnet testing through CLI works fine. 
but sam local start-api or sam local invoke or sam local invoke-lambda etc commands are giving errors.
```

I didn't add any code. just the code that comes with AWS Lambda Project in Visual studio.

SAM and docker versions are below.

```
SAM CLI, version 0.19.0
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
```

Following commands work fine:

```
sam build
sam package --output-template template.yaml --profile personal --s3-bucket wp-bucket
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file C:\Projects\apitest\apitesting\sam-app\template.yaml --profile personal --region us-east-1 --stack-n
ame mystackapi --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
sam local generate-event apigateway > testApiRequest.json
```

following 2 commands do not run:

```
sam local generate-event apigateway > testApiRequest.json
```

Visual studio Function.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace apitesting
{
    public class Functions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor that Lambda will invoke.
        /// </summary>
        public Functions()
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// A Lambda function to respond to HTTP Get methods from API Gateway
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <returns>The list of blogs</returns>
        public APIGatewayProxyResponse Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine("Get Request\n");

            var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = "Hello AWS Serverless",
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
            };

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Template.yaml is

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Sample SAM Template for sam-app

  '
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10
Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://wp-bucket/c0851f265e7cd94536333e901f8054e2
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Properties:
            Method: get
            Path: /hello
          Type: Api
      Handler: apitesting::apitesting.Functions::Get
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

sam local generate-event apigateway > testApiRequest.json

```
Getting following error:

2019-08-15 12:24:23 Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs8.10)
2019-08-15 12:24:23 Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials

Fetching lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10 Docker container image......
2019-08-15 12:24:24 Mounting C:\Projects\apitest\apitesting\sam-app\.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.35/containers/1d2500666d8536d247c6935727f517240b575dab2274c1b5e8bfdc2068ee9da2/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli(prog_name="sam")
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metrics.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metrics.py", line 65, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\invoke\cli.py", line 58, in cli
    parameter_overrides)  # pragma: no cover
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\invoke\cli.py", line 102, in do_cli
    stderr=context.stderr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\lib\local_lambda.py", line 93, in invoke
    self.local_runtime.invoke(config, event, debug_context=self.debug_context, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\lambdafn\runtime.py", line 86, in invoke
    self._container_manager.run(container)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\manager.py", line 98, in run
    container.start(input_data=input_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\container.py", line 189, in start
    real_container.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\models\containers.py", line 392, in start
    return self.client.api.start(self.id, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 1091, in start
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"setenv: invalid argument\"": unknown")
```

for this command:

```
sam local start-api

    2019-08-15 12:26:35 Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
    2019-08-15 12:26:35 You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
    2019-08-15 12:26:35  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    2019-08-15 12:26:56 Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs8.10)
    2019-08-15 12:26:56 Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials

    Fetching lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10 Docker container image......
    2019-08-15 12:26:58 Mounting C:\Projects\apitest\apitesting\sam-app\.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
    [32mSTART RequestId: bef53df5-4308-10b6-9922-b4dc94ea0885 Version: $LATEST[0m
    [31mUnable to import module 'app': Error[0m
    [31m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)[0m
    [32mEND RequestId: bef53df5-4308-10b6-9922-b4dc94ea0885[0m
    [32mREPORT RequestId: bef53df5-4308-10b6-9922-b4dc94ea0885     Duration: 2.94 ms       Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 31 MB  [0m
    2019-08-15 12:27:01 Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'errorType', 'stackTrace', 'errorMessage'} in {'errorMessage': "Cannot find module '/var/task/app'", 'errorType': 'Error', 'stackTrace': ['Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)', 'Module.require (module.js:596:17)', 'require 
 internal/module.js:11:18)']}
    2019-08-15 12:27:01 Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers, multiValueHeaders or statusCode in the response object). Response received: {"errorMessage":"Cannot find module '/var/task/app'","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)","Module.require (module.js:596:17)","require (internal/module.js:11:18)"]}
```

Comment: Please reformat your question. It's currently all formatted as a code block.

Comment: Thank you Arnaud for editing my post. This is my second post in more than 3 years so apologies for badly formatted code. Can anyone please provide suggestions that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me with the 
`sam local invoke...`

But I used this command 
`sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy > testApiRequest.json`
in order to get the 
`sam local start-api`
to work.